# C# mongo near queries unable to find index for $geoNear

Tags: c#, mongodb

I created the following index on my Mongo db

```
db.AddressInformations.createIndex({"Address.Gps" : "2dsphere"}, {bits:26})
```

in the mongo shell I can run this and it works

```
db.AddressInformations.find({"Address.Gps": {
$near: {
    $geometry:{ 
        type: "Point", 
        coordinates: [-84.26060492426588, 30.45023887165371]
    }
}
}})
```

However if I try and run either of these

```
db.AddressInformations.find({"Address.Gps" : {$geoNear:[-81.941429, 26.639506]}})

db.AddressInformations.find({"Address.Gps" : {$near:[-81.941429, 26.639506]}})
```

I get this error

```
unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

In my C# code I also try and run this query and get the same error

```
var query = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Near("Address.Gps",
             GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(lon, lat)));

var returnItems = await MongoCollection.FindAsync(query, findOptions, 
                         cancellationToken.Token);

return await returnItems.ToListAsync(cancellationToken.Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

C# MongoDB has certain limitations and usually is behind in terms of features as compare to MongoDB shell.

Try following code snippet:

```
var query = "{'Address.Gps': {$near: {$geometry:{type: 'Point', coordinates: [-84.26060492426588, 30.45023887165371]}}}}";

var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument> (query);

var result = db.AddressInformations.find(filter);
```

Here I'm converting MonogoDB shell query to BsonDocument and using it as filter to C# collection API.

I have filed a feature request to  MongoDB in past. see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1585